# Autocad: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin, autolisp

what's the use of this folder? I need to load a lisp in automatic way without using acad.lsp and acaddoc.lsp. Will I find there the answer?
I'm asking that because i saw an add-on i have load something from there.

Thanks guys,
Dennis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load LISP (or any other customization) on AutoCAD is quite easy with Autoloader approach. Just create a PackageContents.xml, place everything inside a .bundle folder and copy/paste at one of predefined locations (c:\program files\autodesk\application plugins).

See a complete description at http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/01/autodesk-autoloader-white-paper.html

Here is a minimal PackageContents.xml sample:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationPackageSchemaVersion="1.0"
AutodeskProduct="AutoCAD"
Name="Minimal LISP"
Description="An AutoCAD LISP Only program"
AppVersion="1.0.0"
HelpFile="./Contents/Resources/Help.html"
Author="Fenton Webb"
Icon="./Contents/Resources/FentiCAD.ico">

  <CompanyDetailsName="FentiCAD"Url="www.FentiCAD.com"Email="fenton.webb@autodesk.com" />
  <ComponentsDescription="Runtime parts">
    <RuntimeRequirementsOS="Win32|Win64|MacOS"Platform="AutoCAD|AutoCAD*"SeriesMin="R18.2"SeriesMax="R19.1" />
    <ComponentEntryAppName="MinimalLISP"Version="1.0.0"ModuleName="./Contents/Runtime/Minimal.cuix" />
    <ComponentEntryAppName="MinimalLISP"Version="1.0.0"ModuleName="./Contents/Runtime/Minimal.lsp"PerDocument="True"/>
  </Components>
</ApplicationPackage>
```

Comment: BTW, you should not place your files under 'Autodesk Shared' folder (this for is for autodesk applications only)

Comment: I spent all the day trying to find the solution. Really thanks man! After that my program will be ready for the distribution :)))

Comment: I've got a question about, will this method work with autocad 2009? Thanks